# RecordsetClone.RecordCount won't return zero

Tags: ms-access, vba

The following function correctly returns numbers if greater than zero. If zero, it does nothing - no zero, no number, not even an error code. The result is not 'null' either. The text box is just blank.

```
Public Function NumRecs() As Integer
Me.RecordsetClone.MoveLast
NumRecs = Me.RecordsetClone.RecordCount
End Function
```

It is on a form whose data comes from:

```
SELECT tblClient.ClientID, tblDisclosure.ID, tblDisclosure.ProbChased 
FROM tblDisclosure INNER JOIN tblClient ON tblDisclosure.Client = tblClient.ClientID 
WHERE (((tblDisclosure.ProbChased) Is Not Null)) ORDER BY tblClient.ClientID ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need should be:

```
Public Function NumRecs() As Integer
    NumRecs = Me.RecordsetClone.RecordCount
End Function
```

It cannot return "nothing", so if that is what you see, the function isn't called.

Comment: Thank you. On further investigation I found that I had made the form 'Allow Additions = False'. I reversed this and the function now works the way I want. I have added a procedure so that if NumRecs > 0 then Allow Additions = False.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely need a zero returned you can check .BOF and .EOF

```
Public Function NumRecs() as Integer
   NumRecs=0
   with Me.RecordsetClone
      If Not (.BOF and .EOF) then
         .MoveLast
         NumRecs=.RecordCountd
      End if
   End with
End Function
```